# Python Selenium unable to find table element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is what the table looks like on the web page (it's just one column):

[image: Here is what the table looks like on the web page]

Here is the HTML of the table I am trying to scrape:

[image: Here is the HTML of the table I am trying to scrape]

If it matters, that table is nested within another table.

Here is my code:

```
    def filter_changed_records():
        # Scrape webpage for addresses from table of changed properties
        row_number = 0
        results_frame = locate_element(
            '//*[@id="oGridFrame"]'
        )
        driver.switch_to.frame(results_frame)
        while True:
            try:
                address = locate_element("id('row" + str(row_number) +
                                         "FC')/x:td")
                print(address)
                changed_addresses.append(address)
                row_number += 1
            except:
                print("No more addresses to add.")
                break
```

As you can see, there is a `<tr>` tag with an id of `row0FC`. This table is dynamically generated, and each new `<tr>` gets an id with a increasing number: `row0FC, row1FC, row2FC` etc. That is how I planned on iterating through all the entries and adding them to a list.

My locate_element function is the following:

```
    def locate_element(path):
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))
        return element
```

It always times out after 50 seconds from not finding the element. Unsure of how to proceed. Is there a better way of locating the element?

**SOLUTION BY ANDERSSON**

```
address = locate_element("//tr[@id='row%sFC']/td" % row_number).text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `XPath` seem to be incorrect.

Try below:

```
address = locate_element("//tr[@id='row%sFC']/td" % row_number)
```

Also note that `address` is a `WebElement`. If you want to get its text content, you should use

```
address = locate_element("//tr[@id='row%sFC']/td" % row_number).text
```

Comment: No luck, sadly. It still can't find it. Does the xpath also need to route through the parent table, or would that not effect it?

Comment: Can you check whether your `table` located inside an `iframe`. Also add `HTML` for the same as text, not as image

Comment: It is in a frame. I left that part out, edited original code in post with those lines.

Comment: Did you miss `return element` in your `locate_element()` definition?

Comment: Somehow that bit got cut off. Yeah, I have that. `locate_element()` works fine for tons of other stuff, so that bit isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: It's a paid site that requires a password to access. I can share the page source, I guess? EDIT: I can send a copy of the source https://pastebin.com/dbScuYZL

Comment: You can use some codesharing service, e.g. https://codeshare.io/G877P4 to share your `HTML` source

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see required table elements on provided `HTML` sample... Did you share correct page source?

Comment: I updated it with the frame source instead of the page source. That should be more helpful, hopefully. The frame isn't nested within another frame.

Comment: `address = locate_element("//tr[@id='row%sFC']/td" % row_number).text` gives me `'525 N Sepulveda Blvd'`. Are you sure you switch to exact iframe?

Comment: That worked when I plugged that line in. Thanks so much for sticking with me in solving this problem this morning!

Answer (score -1):

Parsing html with selenium is slow. I would use BeautifulSoup for that.

Suppose you have loaded the page in driver it would be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
....

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
td_list = soup.findAll('td')
for td in td_list:
    try:
        addr = td['title']
        print(addr)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Is the difference in speed big enough to justify migrating my entire script to it? It's about 500 lines of selenium so I don't want to spend the time switching to beautifulsoup if it isn't a huge difference.

Comment: That depend on the amount of pages your getting info from and how many element you're using selenium to grab. If it's a one off and time is not important, stick to selenium. In future project parse the code with something else if speed is important...

Comment: I just did a speed test. Setup was as follows. I used selenium to pull data from the white pages. 1 page that has 100 hits. Each hit contains in a result block which holds both name, address and phone number. I did 10 loops for both selenium and BeautifulSoup (html.parser) where I extracted both name, address and phone number (3 find-commands) - which for both BeautifulSoup and Selenium sums up to 3010 find-commands (10 loops * 100 person * 3 + 10*1 find result block-command) in total. With soup the total time is 13 seconds. For selenium 165 seconds - which makes soup about 12 times faster.

Comment: Wow. That's awesome. I think I'll migrate

Comment: and if you feed soup only the part of the html, that holds your data (which I did in the example) your speed improves comparing to what I did in my answer about (where I fed soup with driver.page_source). This is done like so: `container = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.relevant.section').get_attribute("outerHTML")` and then feeding only the container object to BeautifulSoup instead of the whole html page.